# Cabal trouble resolving dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm tring to install the package `cabal-debian` globally using `cabal v2-install cabal-debian` and get this error message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.1... (user goal)
[__1] trying: binary-0.8.7.0 (user goal)
[__2] next goal: ghc (user goal)
[__2] rejecting: ghc-8.6.5/installed-8.6... (conflict: binary==0.8.7.0, ghc =>
binary==0.8.6.0/installed-0.8...)
[__2] trying: ghc-8.6.5
[__3] rejecting: ghc:-buildable (conflict: base==4.12.0.0/installed-4.1...,
ghc -buildable => base<0)
[__3] rejecting: ghc:+buildable (manual flag can only be changed explicitly)
[__3] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, ghc, ghc:buildable)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: binary, base, ghc, ghc:buildable
Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

I am using `cabal 3.0.0.0` and have `ghc 8.6.5` installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, this looks like you have a version of `binary` installed that isn't compatible with the boot libraries that come with the compiler. I recommend that you edit the file

```
~/.ghc/<something>-8.6.5/environments/default
```

and delete the line that mentions `binary`, then try again. (The `<something>` is almost certainly `x86_64-linux`.)

Comment: what is your guess on how this could have happend?

Comment: @Ackdari Presumably you asked to install some library that depends on `binary` (perhaps `binary` itself) but not the boot libraries that conflict with the chosen `binary` version.

Comment: Holy cow it worked! I looked at this answer and said "Yeah that looks like a lovely way to brick my Haskell install", but I was desperate and tried it anyway. Worked like a charm!